# JavaFX polygon resize using anchor save to background image

Tags: canvas, anchor, javafx, polygon

I create shapes in JavaFx using polygons and anchors.Using these I can modify the shapes on screen.After I finish editing the polygon,I need to right click and integrate the created polygon into the background image.I managed to create a polygon and turn into an image I use in the background.I dont't know how to modify the image to add another polygon to it after I finish editing a new one.I used StackPane to add the image in the background and the polygon+anchors on top of it.Sorry for not posting any code but I'm not at my computer now.Any suggestion is welcomed.